# EPS to HTML or PSD to HTML, which is the most "normal" scenario for a web developer?

Tags: html, photoshop, adobe-illustrator, eps, psd

I'm doing slicing for more than 13+ years and I have converted only:

```
PNG to HTML
PSD to HTML
```

Whenever the client had only an EPS file and/or also a PSD file with one single layer, I got later the PSD file with all layers. Of course this is possible by exporting the file from Illustrator.

My question is if exporting an EPS file from Illustrator into a multi layered PSD it can be considered officially a designer's job or it is more suitable for a developer. Should developers have Adobe Illustrator?

I need arguments also. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that converting your EPS file to PSD is more of a designer job because it involves manipulating graphical files. But then again slicing a PSD can also be considered manipulating a graphical file.

It's kind of a blurry border here, but since Illustrator is build specifically for vectorial design and vectorial file manipulation, I'd say the task should be assigned to a designer rather then to a front-end developer.

I don't think I've heard many developers having Illustrator as part of their "arsenal" but it's always a good ideea to have it installed if the need arises :)

Long story short: Yes, the task should be assigned to a designer.